# How to make auto-indent work in Eclipse for jsp/jsf/xhtml pages?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, auto-indent

I'm using Eclipse Helios with WTP.
I would like eclipse to auto-indent jsf pages. Eclipse fails to do that properly and I didn't find any place that I can configure what I want.

Examples of bad auto-indentation

```
<li><c:if test="${userSession.loggedUser eq null}">
```

also

```
</h:outputLink></li>
```

The only configuration I found is in Preferences -> XML -> Editor and there are only a handful of options none of which say **split new elements on a new line** although it has the useless **split attributes on a new line**.

Currently I'm jsf + richfaces, but this problem exists since jsp was the top of the web stack.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also checked the available preferences under HTML?

Comment: Yes, I have. Actually there don't seem to be many options at all. That what my problem is.